# How to extract road details from Google map?

Tags: applications, gps, google-maps

I have a problem of getting GPS locations regarding to a road from google maps android API. How can we get a GPS location range regarding to a road? Is there any way to identify a marked point is within a road?

Comment: This might be one for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ as it isn't necessarily specific to Android.